# Unity camera rotate by mouse input, How to rotate the move to the default position？

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Camera rotate by mouse input, How to rotate the move to the default position?

```
public class CameraOrbit : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float turnSpeed = 1.0f;
    public Transform player;
    
    private Vector3 offset;
    
    private void Start()
    {
        offset = new Vector3(0, 2.5f, -5);
    }
    
    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            offset = Quaternion.AngleAxis(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * turnSpeed, Vector3.up) * offset;
            transform.localPosition = offset;
            transform.LookAt(player.position);
        }
    }
}
```

This kind of thing moves directly into position and I want to smooth it over.

```
public void RevertCamera()
{
    offset = new Vector3(0, 2.5f, -5);
    transform.localPosition = offset;
    transform.LookAt(player.position);
}
```

I have tried multiple variations of this, but none of them seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the easiest way is to use the camera's transform's `RotateAround(...)` method:

```
void LateUpdate 
{
    if(Input.GetMouseDown(0))
    {
        float delta = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * turnSpeed;
        transform.RotateAround(player.position, Vector3.up, delta);
    }
}
```

(taken from: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html)

Suggestion: I usually set up a camera rig, if I want to control camera movement focused on a certain target.
Though this might be overengineered for a simple RotateAround call.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to achieve smooth transitions. I would advise you to use Slerp on the Quaternion and interpolate between your 2 rotation points.

**Slerp Example:**

```cs
// Interpolates rotation between the rotations "from" and "to"
// (Choose from and to not to be the same as
// the object you attach this script to)

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SlerpExample: MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField]private Transform from;
    [SerializeField]private Transform player;

    private bool revertCamera = false;
    private float timeCount = 0.0f;

    private void Update() {
        timeCount = timeCount + Time.deltaTime;

        if (revertCamera) {
            timeCount = 0.0f;
            transform.rotation = Quaternion
                .Slerp(from.rotation, player.rotation, timeCount);

            if (transform.rotation == player.rotation) {
                reverCamera = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private void RevertCamera() {
        revertCamera = true;
    }
}
```

[Slerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Slerp.html)

Comment: I used @Thomas to solve the problem and thank you for your answer :)